# retrieve user's data after signing in using express and JWT

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I'm new to node.js and express, I've implemented signing in and verification functionality using JWT cookies, how after verifying the user is signed in I can retrieve his username to use in other pages?

This is my auth.js file where I have the login and verify functions:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const UserDB = require('../models/UserModel');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

exports.login = function(req,res,next){

    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;

    UserDB.lookup(username,function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log("error looking up user",err);
            return res.status(401).send();
        }
        if(!user){
            console.log("user "+username+" not found");
            return res.status(401).send();
        }

        bcrypt.compare(password,user.password,function(err,result){
            if(result){
                console.log("confirm")
                let payload = {username:username};
                let accessToken = jwt.sign(payload,process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,{expiresIn: 120});
                res.cookie("jwt",accessToken);
                next();
            }
            else
            { 
                return res.status(403).send();
            }
        });
    });
};

exports.verify = function(req,res,next){
    let accessToken = req.cookies.jwt;
    if(!accessToken){
        return res.status(403).send();
    }
    let payload;
    try{
        payload = jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
        next();
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log("Not authorized")
        res.status(401).send();
    }
};
```

I've read that I can add it in the verification function but I don't know how, I want to use it as follows:

```
exports.admin_panel = function(req,res){
  res.render('adminpanel',{
    'user': //add the username 
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `verify()` function like this:

```js
exports.verify = function(req,res,next){
    let accessToken = req.cookies.jwt;
    if(!accessToken){
        return res.status(403).send();
    }
    
    
    let payload = jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

    if(!payload){
    console.log("Not authorized")
    res.status(401).send();
    }

    req.user = payload.username
    next();
};
```

Comment: I tried it but for some reason now the verification function doesn't work correctly, it goes into the catch and send me 401 when I try to login

Comment: @Abdelrhmann02 what is result of ```console.log(req.cookies.jwt)```. also check if token is **expired**

Comment: it returns this `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFiZG8iLCJpYXQiOjE2NTE0MjgyMjYsImV4cCI6MTY1MTQyODM0Nn0.9tM8xyTP3TgcHz9AHwUlE7xfdocOVxTn5sDibYVrxbc` and it's not expired I checked

Comment: this is how verify function looks now `let payload;
    try{
        payload = jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
        req.user = user;
        next();
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log("Not authorized")
        res.status(401).send();
    }` and every time I get the "Not authorized" in console

Comment: You mean `req.user = payload.username`, right?

Comment: yes, it is up to you